# Split values in column by column number with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, split

I am trying to scrape data from html tables with python using pandas. These tables are on urls, so i create a list

**Each table has two values on some cells on specific columns**. I manage to read all the data, print them and save them on a csv file. This is the way i do it.
My code so far is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import pandas as pd
urls = ["https://url?date=2020-12-31", "https://url?date=2020-12-30", "https://url?date=2020-12-29"]
df = pd.DataFrame(urls)

        for url in urls:
            df = pd.read_html(url, parse_dates=True)  
            print(df[0])
            df[0].to_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
            print ("Data have been extracted successfully")
```

On the output, the two values of some cells they appear in a line e.g € 14,720 55.3%.
As you see, i have an amount and a percentage on the same line, plus some empty columns appearing with NaN.
I want to separate the amount with the percentage by the second space, and transfer the percentage in a new column (Percentage) next to this.
Im trying with str.split but i get error message that *"Dataframe object has no attribute list"*.
Also other methods i try i get same error that Dataframe object has no attribute.....
i convert the urls list to Dataframe with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(urls)
```

but i still dont understant if this is the way to convert because it keeps giving me the error.

Also when i try to delete the empty columns with

```
df.drop(df.columns[[0,1]], axis=1)
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'drop'

i get the same message.

So, two things. How i separate by second space, values from specific column and put them in a new column next and then it would be cool if i could drop the empty columns. Either by column number or by empty cells.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give some example of what's in the first row i.e. `df[0]` so we can reproduce the error? The error message seems to state that you're trying to access a column called `list`, which doesn't exist in the dataframe.

Comment: 1st row on table is this (have cut some columns)
In total there are 11 columns

0          NaN  10:05   -   € 14,720 55.3%      € 7,386 44%      € 9,397 56%

Comment: UPDATE. I have managed to split the columns i want and generate new columns and put the values that i split in these new columns. 
The problem is that i split in the first space while i want to split on the second space and i cannot make it work.
I have tried every solutions by googling, but nothing works.

Comment: Do you want to split the string on *every* second space, or just the once? For example, if you had `"A B C D E"`, do you want `"A B","C D","E"` or `"A B","C","D","E"`?

Comment: I have a string on each cell that is in the form of  € 1,390 75% You see there are two spaces. One after the currency symbol and the second one after the number. I have managed to separate the string on the first space and to create two new columns. But on the one new column it places the € symbol and on the other the rest numbers. I want to get rid of the € symbol, keep the money amount in one column and the percentage in another column.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments, this is what you're looking for:

```
# simple reproducible example
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['values'] = ['€ 1,390 75%','€ 45 12.8%','€ 14,390 9%']

# this removes the currency symbol
def remove_symbol(x):
    x = x.split(' ')
    return ' '.join(x[1:])

# this splits the remaining string into two columns on the space seperator
df[['money','percentage']] = df['values'].apply(lambda x: remove_symbol(x)).str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
```

Output:

```
    values      money   percentage
0   € 1,390 75% 1,390   75%
1   € 45 12.8%  45      12.8%
2   € 14,390 9% 14,390  9%
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve it with this code.
thank you for any help..

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import pandas as pd


#DATAFRAME AS OBJECT
df = pd.DataFrame()


urls = ["urllink"]

for url in urls:
        
        #READ URLS
        df = pd.read_html(url, parse_dates=True)
        df = df[0] 
           
    
        #SPLIT COLUMN ON 2nd SPACE AND CREATE 2 NEW COLUMNS WITH € AND %
        new1 = df["1"].str.split(" ", n = 2, expand = True)
        df["1 ΣΕ €"]= new1[1]
        df["1 ΣΕ %"]= new1[2]
        
    
        newX = df["Χ"].str.split(" ", n = 2, expand = True)
        df["Χ ΣΕ €"]= newX[1]
        df["Χ ΣΕ %"]= newX[2]
        
        
        new2 = df["2"].str.split(" ", n = 2, expand = True)
        df["2 ΣΕ €"]= new2[1]
        df["2 ΣΕ %"]= new2[2]
        
    
        newOVER = df["OVER"].str.split(" ", n = 2, expand = True)
        df["OVER ΣΕ €"]= newOVER[1]
        df["OVER ΣΕ %"]= newOVER[2]
        
        
        newUNDER = df["UNDER"].str.split(" ", n = 2, expand = True)
        df["UNDER ΣΕ €"]= newUNDER[1]
        df["UNDER ΣΕ %"]= newUNDER[2]
        
        #DELETE UNWANTED COLUMNS
        df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11]], axis=1, inplace=True)
        
        
        print(df)
        
        df.to_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```